# Some images/icons not working on 1st load

Tags: font-awesome, opencart2.x

Not loading few icons when it loads 1st time at any browser in **OpenCart 2.0.3.1**, also add to cart button dose not works at 1st time load.

Site URL- `http://www.allcardecor.com/`

I tried clearing my cache, reinstalling all my modules.

Comment: but everything loads after refreshing the site.

Comment: Was my answer below helpful?  If this did in fact solve your problem, please mark it as the answer.  If you have other questions, let me know.

Comment: hey there, thanks.  i redirected www to non www from cpanel and it worked, still looking through CORS

Comment: Do you mind marking my answer as correct?

Answer (score 1):

You're having a cross-domain issue with your request.  When I load that page in my console I see this error:

> Font from origin 'http://allcardecor.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.allcardecor.com' is therefore not allowed access.

You'll note that your site http://www.allcardecor.com, is calling on the FontAwesome files from http://allcardecor.com.  The browser is seeing this as two different domains.

You'll want to setup a canonical name for one of the domains in your DNS so that it's recognized as a legitimate alias for the other.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record

You should also setup CORS so that you can call scripts from approved sites without running into cross domain errors:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 0):

For someone who might still need this. The problem is due to cross domain issue as Jocko has pointed out.

Another way to fix this is to redirect all requests to your site to particular subdomain, e.g. yourdomain.com => www.yourdomain.com and link all resources as such.

On Apache, in `.htaccess` file, add the following lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

On Nginx, checkout this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-nginx-on-centos-7).